# How do I play this part in 'Trois pièces brèves'?

Tags: notation, french-horn

How do I play this part on my french horn?
From Jacques Ibert - Trois pièces brèves

[image: trois piece breves]

Comment: It's shorthand notation to make the copyist's job easier.  Just alternate between the two notes at a comfortable speed.  I suppose that on French horn you might not be able to alternate between the notes as quickly as on, say, piano.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't circled the other instances of the tremolo, I'm guessing you're looking for a good fingering combination, not just an explanation of the notation.

I would play this on the B-flat horn using fingering 2-3 for the C-sharps and just 3 for the D-naturals.  You could also try the F horn with 1-2 for the C-Sharp and 1 for the D, but that might be a little squirrelly on the F horn.

Comment: I should have circled the other parts too. It's the tremolo you already mentioned which I don't know how to play. Nevertheless I'll try the combination, thanks.

Comment: In that case, I would recommend looking at the answers for on the question linked by @Dom above.